# how to get the color of a single pixel in p5js

Tags: p5.js

i am trying to get the color of a pixel below a player and if it is blue i stop them from falling down. for some reason it detects the color but the if statement never runs even though it matches. here is code:

```js
gravity(){
  if (this.y <= 400 - this.scale){
    let gc = get(this.x, this.y + 25);
    print(gc);
    if (gc == [0, 0, 255, 255]){
      this.canGravity = false;
    }
    else {
      this.canGravity = true;
    }
    if (this.canGravity == true){
      this.y += 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, your issue is the equality check.

Take a look at the following example:

```js
let first = [1, 2];
let second = [1, 2];
console.log(first === second); // false;
```

The best way to check for equality of two arrays in JavaScript is to loop through each element and perform a comparison, so your example might look like:

```js
if (arraysEqual(gc, [0, 0, 255, 255])) {
  this.canGravity = false;
}

...
function arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.length === arr2.length && arr1.every((value, index) => value === arr2[index]);
}
```

Or even simpler for your scenario:

```js
if (gc[0] === 0 && gc[1] === 0 && gc[2] === 255 && gc[3] === 255) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: thanks this got it working, but i seem to have a problem where the falling is stuttering. any way to fix that?

Comment: That's a different question altogether, maybe worth asking that separately and accepting this answer if it solved the question you originally asked.